# free text contains separator: concatenate columns

Tags: r

I have a ;-separated file, unfortunately, the strings in column B are not quoted. Even worse, I have:

integer; some text; and some other text; code. Resulting in A; B; C; null when reading my file.

How can I check if the extra column is not empty and than concatenate B and  (the wrong) C?

first rows of my file:

```
iEpisodeId;iPatientId;sTitle;sICPC;dStart;dEnd;bProblem;
1063862;1001513;St Na Hartinfarct;K76.02;1-2-1992;NA;1;
1063865;1001513;Hypercholesterolaemie;  Familiair   9.0;T93.01;1-1-1991;11-   12-2003;1;
1063866;1001513;Algemene Episode;NA;31-7-1995;NA;0;
1024407;1002509;Algemene Episode;NA;1-2-1989;NA;0;
```

The second row (1063865) is the one giving trouble (and 171.000 other rows...).
I would like to concatenate 'Hypercholesteroaemie' with 'familiair 9.0' to column 3 and shift all others > 3 columns to the left by 1.

Reading itself is not the problem:

```
test <- read_delim("test.csv", delim=";", col_name=T)
```

However, I get the extra col:

```
names(test)
[1] "iEpisodeId" "iPatientId" "sTitle"     "sICPC"      "dStart"     "dEnd"       "bProblem"   NA
```

Comment: a small sample of data would be much more helpful than the description of your problem, please post some sample data

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? It will be much more helpful for others rather than you trying to explain/describe your data

Comment: If you are using `read.table` to read the data from the file, you might find it useful to look at the `colClasses` option, but it's hard to know from your description.

Comment: Reading is not the problem,

Comment: The extra column is because each line ends with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file line by line:

```
library(stringr)
fileName <- "new 3.txt"
conn <- file(fileName,open="r")
linn <-readLines(conn)
myTable = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = length(linn)))
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
  line = linn[i]
  if(str_count(line,";") ==8){
    index <- gregexpr(pattern =';',line)[[1]][3]
    line <- gsub(paste("^(.{",index-1, "}).", sep=""), "\\1 ", line) 
  }
    myTable[i,] = strsplit(line, split=";")[[1]]
}
close(conn)
```

Comment: Your code gives me:  head(linn)
[1] "iEpisodeId;iPatientId;sTitle;sICPC;dStart;dEnd;bProblem;;"                            
[2] "1063862;1001513;St Na Hartinfarct;K76.02;1-2-1992;NULL;1;;"                           
[3] "1063865;1001513;Hypercholesterolaemie  Familiair   9.0;T93.01;1-1-1991;11-12-2003;1;;" I still get the empty cols I have to get rid of, so only counting the ;'s won't do I'm afraid. I have to check if the 8th or 9th col is filled, if so...concatenate col 3 and 4

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can verify if the second "half" column is NA  and not do the gsub line, but do a substring instead,  if that's your need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! Nearly there. It runs fine (although after adding linn[i] = gsub(pattern = ";;",replace = "",linn[i]) at the beginning to get rid of the extra cols at the end) when I have one ; too much (thus: 8 cols). But I also have 9, 10 cols (with same problem). A last suggestion to solve this? Perhaps run multiple times?

Comment: are all the ";"s in the same "text column"? (As in: colA;colB;partialcolC;partialcolC;partialcolC;colD?)

Comment: Yep. There's only one text column (C) and if errors occur, it's in C (creatign C1, C2, C3 etc).

Comment: It's just a one-time script don't stress jourself! Do more than one if clause and personalize the gsub! XD

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to read and skip the first line (containing the header)? Unfortunately, everything was fine on my test file, but on the real data (>170.000 rows) I get: